# php auto mailer addAddress

Tags: php, mysql, function, session, phpmailer

I want to send otp mail to user by fetching email value from database . I am using php auto mailer . It works when i use mail address directly but when i retrieve it from database i cant send it . Can anyone please help me with sending it .

```
    function mailit()
    {
            $rand=rand(100000,999999);
            $user=$_SESSION['user'];

            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `doctor_login` SET `otp`='$rand' WHERE `doctor_id`='1'");

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'myusername ';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587 ;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            $mail->setFrom('dont_reply_back@example.xyz');
            $mail->addAddress('$row');     // Add a recipient
            $mail->addReplyTo('dont_reply_back@example.xyz');


            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'THis is your OTP';
            $mail->Body    = 'Your otp is '.$rand; 

            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }        
  }
```

Code for retrieving and displaying of email

```
    $mailadd=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `doctor_email` FROM `doctor_login` WHERE `doctor_id`='1'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($mailadd,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['doctor_email'];
    $row2=$rowa['doctor_email'];
    echo $row2;
```

i have used both $row and $row2 in $mail->addAddress but doesnt seem to work . What changes can i do . it works whwn i give a specific address

Comment: So WHERE is the code that gets the doctors email address with relation to the `mailit()` function?

Comment: All looks like a variable SCOPE issue to me! Remember `$row` will not be visiblle inside a function if you create it outside the function. So pass it as a parameter to `mailit($docs_email)`

Comment: What is the SELECT supposed to do in the `mailint` function?

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is a scope issue. If you are calling this code in the main body of the code

```
$mailadd=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `doctor_email` 
                            FROM `doctor_login` 
                            WHERE `doctor_id`='1'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($mailadd,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Then I assume you call `mailit()` after this, so pass the data you want to use as a parameter to the `mailit()` function so it is available inside the function scope.

```
function mailit($row)
{
    $rand=rand(100000,999999);
    $user=$_SESSION['user'];

    $sql=mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `doctor_login` SET `otp`='$rand' WHERE `doctor_id`='1'");

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myusername ';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587 ;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('dont_reply_back@example.xyz');
    $mail->addAddress($row['doctor_email']);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('dont_reply_back@example.xyz');


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'THis is your OTP';
    $mail->Body    = 'Your otp is '.$rand; 

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }        
}

$mailadd=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `doctor_email` 
                            FROM `doctor_login` 
                            WHERE `doctor_id`='1'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($mailadd,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

mailit($row);
```

You should have been getting errors from your original code so in future add the following:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
// if you are using the `mysqli` API
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Not only this one mon ami @FunkFortyNiner